# Having trouble with getting a json timed event to work

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a command that when executed, will write to a json file in the same directory and send a message every 24 hours. And I've got it to work partially, however in the console when the message is supposed to be executed it spits out an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM71D.png).

Here is my code, I'm honestly puzzled on why it's not working.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
```

async def message(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == 'id here':
        phrase = " ".join(args)

```
    time = datetime.datetime.now()

    try:
        data["24h"][ctx.message.channel.id] = {
            "time": time.strftime("%m:%d:%H:%M"),
            "message": phrase,
            "just_sent": False

        }
        await bot.say("Succesfully added a message to be said every 24 hours!")
    except Exception as err:
        await bot.say("An error has occured!")
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    #save data to file
    with open("data.json", "w") as write_file:
        json.dump(data, write_file)
```

Comment: Please show the error message in the question. The error is self-explanatory as it says the variable `just_sent` is not defined.

Comment: There wasn't any other errors in the console apart from a Traceback and 'Ignoring exception in on_ready'